# Why my Web API Net Core 3.1 gives me 404 when it deployed on CentOS 7?

Tags: asp.net-core

I made a simple Net Core Web API, it works properly on local machine, but it gives me 404 - Page not found when it deployed on CentOS 7.. what I missed?

my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}.
```

my program.cs

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:5008");
            });
```

I use default WeatherForecastController.cs that comes as default example for a project.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

it runs properly on my local machine, but it gives me 404 - Page not found when it deployed on centos 7

Comment: Have you ever installed the .net core SDK and .net Core Runtimes in CentOS? And have you ever configured the firewall, whether the related port is enabled? Here are some related articles about Hosting asp.net core on CentOS, you could refer them: [link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1), [link 2](https://medium.com/@muhamadiqbal2106/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-centos-7-redhat-7a4dcb2b450a) and [link 3](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-web-application-on-centos-7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on program.cs file.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .UseKestrel(opts =>
                    {
                    opts.ListenLocalhost(5008);

                     });  
            });
```